# String that ends wih a single underscore character

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the correct regular expression that detects string that end with a single underscore, e.g. `hello_, this_`. So far I have `re.match("[aA-zZ](_)", string)` but detects strings like, day__, ball__, i.e, with two underscores which i do not want. Any ideas how to get string with a single underscore in the end.

Thanks

Comment: add a `$` at the end

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly the regex you're using? Because on my machine, `re.match("[aA-zZ](_)", "day__")` returns None.

Comment: @Kevin Could be a locale issue; `ord("A") < ord("_") < ord("z")`, which means the bracket expression could be matching the first `_`.

Comment: @Darkmoor Try a less ambiguous bracket expression like `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: @chepner, I agree that it's a problem that `[aA-zZ]` can match non-alphanumeric characters such as `[\\]^_` and tilde. But I was more referring to the fact that it matches only one character, and that we're missing a `+` or `*` in the pattern.

Comment: @Kevin Ah, right; I always forget which of `match` and `search` is implicitly anchored to the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
re.search(r"(?<!_)_$", s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oYG6su/1). See the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<!_)` - a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that makes sure there is no `_` immediately the left of the current position
- `_` - an underscore
- `$` - end of string.

Note you need `re.search` that looks for a match anywhere inside a string, not `re.match` that matches only at the start of a string.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex:

```
REGEX = re.compile(r'[^_]_$')
REGEX.search(string)`
```

Comment: You can safely remove `.*` from your regex, +1

Comment: Definetly! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could also update your character class to use a-z and A-Z and then match a single underscore:

```
[a-zA-Z]_$
```

For example using [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

```
pattern = "[a-zA-Z]_$"
re.search(pattern, "day__")
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/d5Gmfb)

Note that `[aA-zZ]` which is the same as `[A-z]` [is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) from `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: I guess it's better to drop `+` from regex as the initial value does not matter here,

Comment: @CodeManiac You are totally right, updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for a regex, but this could be done also by simply:

```
s = "hello__"

s.endswith("_") and not s[:-1].endswith("_")
# False
```

Comment: No need to make a copy of the list with a slice: `not s.endswith("__")`.